# How to use I3 instances

Tags: configuration, window-manager, i3, wmctrl

I know I can use assign with instance like this:

```
assign [instance="main terminal"] $ws2
```

But, how can I start an application and assign it a certain instance name?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't launch any application with your own predefined instance name because it is set by application itself. But you could use common command line options of UI tookits to override it:

1. GTK+: `--name name`, source: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-running.html
2. Qt5: `-qwindowtitle title`, source: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/qt5options.7.html